# implementing a floating sidebar in HTML, which stays visible within the boundaries of page header and page footer

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have seen several questions about floating or fixed sidebars on Stackoverflow, but I could find none that covers this scenario.

Take a look at this page as an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131(v=vs.71).aspx

When the page is scrolled up, the sidebar also scrolls up with it, until its top edge hits the top of the window. As the scrolling continues, the side bar stays fixed in its place until the page footer reaches up and pushes the sidebar up with itself.

Therefore, the sidebar is always trapped between the page header and the page footer, but within that limitation, it tries to stay visible as much as possible.

This is done by using javascript. I was wondering if you guys have already achieved something like this, or if you know of a solution, that you can share here.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at this JSFiddle someone made: http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/VtPcm/

Comment: Thank you very much BeatAlex - that was quick - yes, that's exacly what I was looking for - I searched a lot, but I guess I should've searched more :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a great tutorial on how to acheive this effect through jQuery... http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-sticky-position/

It uses jQuery `.addClass()` to add a class to the element when a certain scroll position is reached.

And the respective `.removeClass()` when the user scrolls back past.

Comment: thank you Andrew - that provides the basic concept, which is also used in the jsfiddle link provided by BeatAlex